# With the Bootstrap Grid System, if you mix and match the sizes, then some column can be covered up?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I mixed and matched different sizes `sm`, `md`, `lg` to see what effect it has:

https://jsfiddle.net/sdLcdrom/

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background: #fa6">hello 1</div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background: #6af">hello 2</div>
        <div class="col-lg-4" style="background: #6fa">hello 3</div>

    </div>

</div>
```

And what behavior should it have?

As it turned out, at the size of `xs`, all 3 div are stacked up, one above the other nicely. At the size of `sm`, which is the width of 768px and up, the first div is covered up (becomes invisible), and at `md`, which is the width of 992px, the second div is also covered up.  Only when it is `lg`, at the width of 1200px and up, then all 3 div are visible again.

I can understand the `xs` and `lg` cases, but how do the `sm` and `md` work out?  I did not expect them to cover each other up but was expecting them to "flow to the next line".

For example, at `sm`, width of 768px and up, I expected the first div to have a width of 4 columns, and div 2 and div 3 both have width of 12 columns, and "wraps", one after the other, to the next line. And the first div should not be covered up.

It didn't happen.  For what reason is that?

Answer (score 3):

You could use clearfix between col classes

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/sdLcdrom/1/

Is this the answer you are looking for? It is really hard to understand what should the end result be, maybe you should create some images visualizing how the grid should respond to different screen sizes.

Also you can assign multiple classes to one div like this

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6"></div>
```

That way the div is 1/3 of the width on medium sized and bigger screens, 1/2 of the width on small screens and 1/1 width on extra-small screens.